# Is there a way to search special LaTeX characters in a PDF file?

Tags: pdf

Especially things like fractions and exponents?

Comment: This is probably not a good/complete/working solution, but may still be of some use. Use pdftk to convert your pdf to uncompressed, e.g., on linux: "pdftk foo.pdf output foou.pdf uncompress" The resulting pdf file is a text file that you can open in an editor. You may be able to find certain strings in there that indicate the presence of a certain thing like a fraction.

Comment: Wow interesting. Does pdftk convert most TeX equations into something that's maybe 50% legible and 50% illegible?

Answer (score 1):

This would probably only work if you use a modern engine (e.g. XeTeX or LuaTeX), use only Unicode in your document (including Unicode-Math), use only OpenType fonts (include OpenType-Math), *and* work with a PDF viewer that can handle Unicode on a Unicode-capable OS.

So it *may* work with the latest ConTeXt MkIV on any recent OS.